# Can I search for my own answers to closed questions?

Tags: support, search

I can search for my own answers using `user:me is:answer` and I can search for closed questions using `closed:1` but can I search for my answers to closed questions?

Put another way can I search for any closed questions which I have answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible using `/search`.

`is:answer` will limit results to only answers; `closed:1` applies only to questions. The result sets for both filters are therefore mutually exclusive which means [we can never get an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20closed:1).

To achieve what you want, the results of `user:me is:answer` needs to be filtered based on the status of the questions they are linked to. I don't think such *join* operations are supported by the search.

Sounds like a job for [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I'm not familiar with SEDE, but here's a query I hacked together by copying bits from existing queries: [Query my answers to closed questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80925/my-answers-to-closed-questions?UserId=115845) (you can change the user id and site to suit your needs).

Comment: Thanks.  Sadly my site (Mathematica) is not on Data Explorer yet but I'll gladly try this when it is.

Comment: Mathematica.SE has been added to the Data Explorer and your query works.  Thanks again!